# 32-bit crypt component running on 64-bit server with 32-bit IIS app!

Tags: com, asp-classic, 64-bit, windows-server-2003, 32-bit

I've got a Classic ASP application running on 64-bit Windows Server 2003 in 32-bit emulation on IIS.

I'm bringing a COM component over from a 32-bit server and wondered how I would install that to be accessible from the Classic ASP app.  I can choose between a 64-bit and a 32-bit version of the component.

Do I:

- install the 32-bit version of the component on the 64-bit server and call it from the Classic ASP app, or
- install the 64-bit version of the component and try to call it from the Classic ASP app?

Answer (score 1):

32 bit application **always** needs 32 bit components and vice versa. 32 bit app cannot load 64 bit dlls (without turning to out of proc solutions).